# c++ Input a number which determines the other numbers and then compare them

Tags: c++

I got this question: I want to write a program to find the minimum of some numbers . The first input number determines how many other numbers will be input. i know how to put the numbers but i don't know how to compare them.

Comment: Show in code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Niladri this is what i've done

Comment: Can you post simple logic of how you think this can be solved. We would work on the program part next.

Comment: @Niladri   int n;
   cin>>n;
   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
   {
       int n1;
       cin>>n1;
       n--;

   }

Comment: Add this detail in the question body. Along with issue you are facing in details.

Comment: @ambikanair i want to input a variable(cin>> x ) for example...which will determine the number of all other variables i need to input...for example x=3 ..i need to input 3 more number...and between all 4 i need to find the minimum

Comment: To find the smallest of two numbers you can do `smallest = std::min(x, y);`

Comment: Assign first element of array to some var say num1.
Start a loop with i = 1 and compare elements with num1. If num1 is greater than any of array element then replace it with that elment otherwise leave it as it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following

```
int N; // total number of input
cin >> N;
int min_val = INT_MAX; //assign maximum integer value to min_val

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //looping through 0 to N-1 to take input and find min
{
   int N1;
   cin >> N1;
   min_val = std::min(min_val, N1); //returns min between min_val and N1 and assigns it to min_val
}

cout << min_val << endl; //print the min_val
```